# System Reboot or shutdown in terminal prompts for retry after closing inhibitors and logging out other users

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I was trying to `shutdown` or `reboot` my system given as a `BYOD` by organization for which I work.

So, far I have tried this :

[image: Shutdwn/reboot]

And as you can see, each time I get this error :

```
User root is logged in on ???
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl reboot -i'
```

I tried `systemctl reboot -i` that is working for a reboot, but none of the above directly works.

So, I wanted to know :

1. What is this inhibitor exactly and what's it significance ?
2. How to close these inhibitors ?
3. Is there any way I can disable this or close this prompt or something like that ?

Comment: Usually `man shutdown` helps, and also, what is preventing you from using the suggested command? This sounds like you are trying to use your Linux experience on iOS, but it does not work the same.

Comment: @ajeh, I have read [man shutdown](https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) well and only thing related to the question that I could found is `All logged-in users are notified that the system is going down and, within the last five minutes of TIME, new logins are prevented.`. Could you please point to any specific man page that you have red and can be of any help to OP ?

Comment: @ajeh. What do you mean by `This sounds like you are trying to use your Linux experience on iOS, but it does not work the same.` ?